# Using ngx-datatable, how do I set a column to display one value, but sort by a different value?

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

In my ngx-datatable, I have a column that shows a string, perhaps say it is money (but doesn't have to be, it can be any string).  If I display the value as a number, it sorts by the numerical value.  If I display the value as money, it sorts the column alphabetically.  What I want to do is sort by the value I assign it to sort by, but display the value I tell it to.  This would need to be done per column.

Now, this isn't good enough to just tell the grid to show the number as money, because that is a coincidence that is just easy to describe the situation.  The display value can be anything, even something that cannot be represented numerically (but I do have a column that has a numerical representation of that string, so this isn't the issue).

What I want to do is set a column up to display the value as how I chose, but when the column header is clicked, it will sort by the numerical representation that I also set.

The examples I have found so far only seem to show how to sort with just one value, or for letting the grid format, I need something a little more sophisticated.  I'm a novice with Angular, so maybe I'm not knowing what to search for.

Comment: you maybe can hide the second column with css

Comment: But I want all the columns to be sortable... I just want to have their be something like a 'DisplayValue' and a 'SortValue'